# Find common Factor of two values

Tags: javascript, for-loop, math, while-loop

I have the following javascript code to calculate the factors of numbers.

```js
var some = [];
var main = "";
var final = "";

function text(data) {
  spliter = data.split(",");

  var k = 0;
  while (k < spliter.length) {
    var meethi = 0;;
    main = spliter[k];

    var datas = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
      meethi = Math.abs(main / i);
      datas = meethi;
      some.push('' + datas + '');
    }
    some.forEach(myFunction);
    final += res + '<br>';
    k++;
  }

  return final;
}
var max = 0;
var res = "";

function myFunction(item) {
  var van = item.split(".");
  if (van[1] == undefined) {
    var high = Math.floor(main / van[0]);
    if (high > max) {
      max = high;
      res += max + ':';
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = text('124,20');
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

My program gets the factors with two values. How do I identify the common factor of both values,only the highest common value?

example like `('124,20') output --> 4`

I tried the code with my own knowledge. If you have any other suggestion for code please tell me and correct my code with my desired result.

***[my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poosanth/p41qkpjs/1/)***

Comment: It seems you can work out the factors, so the common factors are the ones which appear in both lists. So what's your problem? Also there are 3 common factors in your example (1,2 & 4) so why would you only want 4 as the result?

Comment: @jamiec ya .. correct  ..need common factor of both. only the highest comman value.

Comment: Ah right, thats known as the greatest common denominator, and is a well known problem as you see from the answer given.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use for the greatest common divisor [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm).

```js
function gcd(k, n) {
    return k ? gcd(n % k, k) : n;
}

console.log(gcd(124, 20));
console.log([10, 500, 600].reduce(gcd));
```

Comment: Dont you just love it when an answer to a question was formulated in 300BC!

Comment: *"granddaddy of all algorithms, because it is the oldest nontrivial algorithm that has survived to the present day."* [donald knuth]

Comment: Thanks..there was only two values.if more the  two like `('10,500,600')`.What should i do?

Comment: You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and `gcd` as callback, because you can chain `gcd` for every part with the result of the former calculation.

Comment: .can you explain how to performing n % k?

Comment: `%` is the modulo or [`remainder operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). it calculates the rest of a division, like 9 / 4 is 2 with a rest of 1.

Comment: oh god that's so beautiful

Comment: In order to reduce the number of total steps by one, make sure the argument for `k` always represents the smallest integer and `n` the greatest; In other words, the input for `gcd()` should be ordered from smallest to greatest (i.e. `50,100` and not `100,50`).